# How do I display the Greek letter Delta in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am creating an XSL-FO document and in the table header I need to display the greek character "delta".  I have searched and tried many things, but none have worked out.

```
<fo:inline font-family="Symbol">
Δ - &#916; - &#0394; <br/>
</fo:inline>
```

Comment: Which FO formatter are you using? Do you get any warning/error message?

Comment: I am not getting any warnings or errors.  I am using version 1.0 with the standard w3.org/1999/XSL/Format.  I don't know if that is what you are referring to.  I know VB, VBS, and can do some stuff with XML/XSL.

Comment: What I mean is, what program are you using to transform the FO file into a PDF (or whatever output you are creating).

Answer (score 1):

The Symbol font **does not use the Unicode mapping** between codepoints and glyphs.

In particular the glyphs for the greek letters (both uppercase and lowercase) are in the places normally occupied by latin letters, so the "uppercase delta" you need is simply a capital D:

```
<fo:inline font-family="Symbol">
D
</fo:inline>
```

Note that for this to work your formatter (you didn't tell us which one you are using) may need some configuring so that it knows where to find the font file.

Comment: this did not work either.
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
    <xsl:include href="../format.xsl"/>`

Comment: The ../format.xsl file just has engineering values formats such as distance, direction, grade, etc.